# Is shebang necessary in git bash scripts on windows

Tags: linux, windows, bash, git-bash

Shebang is the first line of a bash script telling where the bash script is executed. In Windows git bash scripts, is it necessary? If not, why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shebangs should never *really* be necessary on any platform. If a shell script lacks a shebang, the script will be interpreted by whatever shell binary was called to interpret it. This is usually the same shell binary as the shell from which you invoked the script. If a shell starts executing a script and finds a shebang pointing to a different shell binary, it will invoke that other shell binary to execute the script.

So shebangs are just overrides, in case someone invokes the script from the wrong shell. Like if you write a script with `bash` in mind, but you're worried a `tcsh` user will invoke it, and you know that `tcsh` won't be able to handle the `bash`-isms you used in the script, you put a `bash` shebang at the top which tells `tcsh` or `zsh` or any other shell that they should hand it off to `bash`.

Comment: A `shebang` specifes which interpreter is to be used to parse and execute the remaining lines in a text file. Valid `shebangs` are not just shells but any interpreter such as `awk`, `perl` or `python`.